# Default profiler_output_name value

Tags: config, xdebug, profiler

I have had some issues with the default `xdebug.profiler_output_name`, as php-fpm is serving all requests from the same process ID, my tools dont seem to work very well ([Webgrind](https://github.com/jokkedk/webgrind) and [Clockwork](https://github.com/itsgoingd/clockwork)).

I watched Dericks youtube video where he recomends using `cachegrind.out.%R` (See 1:15 at https://youtu.be/ttQgLBSpVvc?t=74)

Have other people had issues with this?

Answer (score 1):

I'm just going to reiterate that using `cachegrind.out.%R` is probably better. If you're still getting clashes, then you can add the `.%u` as well (which is for microseconds since 1970).